# cURLing to a remote server to send email

Tags: php, email, curl

My hosting provider doesn't allow access to external SMTP mail servers. The problem is that some emails don't get sent using the internal server.

What are the dangers in posting data to a remote server to send emails?

Answer (score 0):

You can post it by HTTPS if your provider does listen to your posted data.
If you are sure that nobody in your server's network catch your outgoing data, you can post it with normal http to your mail server (just simple php script) which then sends mail

Answer (score 0):

I guess you what you mean is that you tried to use curl to send mails via remote servers and your host won't grant you usage of curl.

There is no inherent danger in sending mails but curl will give you a very powerful networking-tool and I guess that is what your host is not keen on handing over to his clients.